# Nokogiri builder performance on huge XML?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, builder

I need to build a huge XML file, about 1-50 MB. I thought that using builder would be effective enough and, well it is, somewhat. The problem is, after the program reaches its last line it doesn't end immediately, but Ruby is still doing something for several seconds, maybe garbage collection? After that the program finally ends.

To give a real example, I am measured the time of building an XML file. It outputs 55 seconds (there is a database behind so it takes long) when the XML was built, but Ruby still processes for about 15 more seconds and the processor is going crazy.

The pseudo/real code is as follows:

```
...
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(doc) do |xml|
  build_node(xml)
end
...

def build_node(xml)
  ...
  xml["#{namespace}"] if namespace  
  xml.send("#{elem_name}", attrs_hash) do |elem_xml|
  ...
    if has_children
      if type
        case type
          when XML::TextContent::PLAIN
            elem_xml.text text_content
          when XML::TextContent::COMMENT
            elem_xml.comment text_content
          when XML::TextContent::CDATA
            elem_xml.cdata text_content
         end
       else
         build_node(elem_xml)
       end
    end
  end
end
```

Note that I was using a different approach using my own structure of classes, and the speed of the build was the same, but at the last line the program normally ended, but now I am forced to use Nokogiri so I have to find a solution.

What I can do to avoid that X seconds long overhead after the XML is built? Is it even possible?

UPDATE:

Thanks to a suggestion from Adiel Mittmann, during the creation of my minimal working example I was able to locate the problem. I now have a small (well not that small) example demonstrating the problem.

The following code is causing the problem:

```
xml.send("#{elem_name}_") do |elem_xml|
  ...
  elem_xml.text text_content #This line is the problem
  ...
end
```

So the line executes the following code based on Nokogiri's documentation:

```
def create_text_node string, &block
  Nokogiri::XML::Text.new string.to_s, self, &block
end
```

[Text node creation code](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Text.html#method-c-new) gets executed then. So, what exactly is happening here?

UPDATE 2:

After some other tries, the problem can be easily reproduced by:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  0.upto(81900) do
    xml.text "test"
  end
end
puts "End"
```

So is it really Nokogiri itself? Is there any option for me?

Comment: Just an FYI: many SO users are wary of questions posted by brand new accounts with generic usernames. There are high abandonment rates associated with them.

Comment: Thank you for the information, to be honest, I didn't even noticed, that I was using generated username => changed now. I am new to this web but I hope that I can be an active part of it.

Comment: Are you reading one XML file and transforming it into another?

Comment: Not precisely, I am reading content from database and use it to construct new XML. Since I was using different approach in past I am almost sure that database alone is not a problem at all. I am trying to avoid constructing DOM by hand = using Nokogiri::XMLElement.new etc.

Comment: Is it possible for you to make a minimal example that triggers the problem?

Comment: I'll do my best, but since the application is complex it will take a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example also takes a long time to execute here. And you were right: it's the garbage collector that's taking so long to execute. Try this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
class A
  def a
    builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
      0.upto(81900) do
        xml.text "test"
      end
    end
  end
end
A.new.a
puts "End1"
GC.start
puts "End2"
```

Here, the delay happens between `"End1"` and `"End2"`. After `"End2"` is printed, the program closes immediately.

Notice that I created an object to demonstrate it. Otherwise, the data generated by the builder can only be garbage collected when the program finishes.

As for the best way to do what you're trying to accomplish, I suggest you ask another question giving details of what exactly you're trying to do with the XML files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if I'll have enough reputation I'll gladly vote up that answer. Since I was aiming to find exactly what a problem is or find solution, this is an accepted answer. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Glad to help. By the way, as far as I know voting up questions or answers has no negative effect on your reputation points. In fact, it will even get you badges sometimes :)

Comment: Yeah only downvotes costs you reputation. Upvotes are free and actually helps the whole community to detect great posts.

Comment: Well I absolutely agree with both of you, but unfortunately it is impossible to give a vote up because I don't have 15 reputation points yet :-) But when I will....like someone said before...I'll be back.

Comment: Ha! I didn't know you needed a minimum amount of points to bless others with upvotes :P

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Ruby built-in (sic) Builder. I use it to generate large XML files as well, and it has such an small footprint.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reaction, Builder seems to be very fast when used on large XML, it is a good suggestion, but it answers only half of the question since i wrote that I need Nokogiri. But thank you anyway, the speed is amazing, many times faster than Nokogiri, maybe I will have to use it in the end.