# Ruby process is at 100% after script ends, profiling, solution?

Tags: ruby, gdb, profiling, nokogiri

**UPDATE:** Problem located in my related question - [Nokogiri performance problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731089/nokogiri-builder-performance-on-huge-xml)

I am having a serious problem with my program. After program reaches it's last statement, Aptana studio shows the program is still running even after the last line was evaluated. Ruby process (after the last line of the script) is still running with 100% CPU usage, it ends after several seconds (15-30 maybe). I am trying to at atleast see where the problem is but after a long time I am still at the beginning. So the question is, what could cause this problem and how can I at least see where the problem is, what are my options? Some additional information:

Aptana debbug mode: After the last line, this will show in the Debug window:
    `<terminated, exit value: 0>path/to/ruby`
But Ruby process is still running and using 100% CPU

I was trying to use gdb to profile Ruby process itself, but ended up with nothing using method described here: [Profilig using gdb](http://blogs.inxsasia.com/kumaresan/2008/02/inspecting-a-li.html). I am using debian squeeze 64-bit and i tried both versions of script (8,12 > 16,24). When I tried to get some stack info I just get this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007f20539a80b8 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
/home/giron/programovani/gdb_init.sh:1: Error in sourced command file:
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on".
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(backtrace) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.
```

After I quit gdb, following output shows up in Aptana console (But this is maybe absolutely useless, probably gdb did this, I don't know):

```
/home/giron/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/RedisXmlConcept/bin/main.rb: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]

-- control frame ----------
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000f68 d:000f68 TOP   
---------------------------

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
/home/giron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_vm_bugreport+0x5f)[0x7f205488216f]
/home/giron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x63274) [0x7f205476a274]
/home/giron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_bug+0xb3) [0x7f205476a413]
/home/giron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x10c215) [0x7f2054813215]
/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0xeff0) [0x7f20544f9ff0]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0xe40b8) [0x7f20539a80b8]
/lib/libgcc_s.so.1(_Unwind_Backtrace+0x49) [0x7f2050d5b599]
/lib/libc.so.6(backtrace+0x4e) [0x7f20539a81ae]
/home/giron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby(_start+0) [0x400890]

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Just to be sure that I have described problem well, last line of code (before this, Nokogiri parsing and work with Redis database is done):

```
puts "End"
```

End is printed out and after this Ruby process will consume 100% CPU for several seconds

This question is related to my previous one here: [Nokogiri performance problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731089/nokogiri-builder-performance-on-huge-xml) where are some more code snippets but since I am focusing on the different approach here (profiling Ruby), I have created new question.

Thank you in advance for any tips, I am pretty much clueless right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was trying to use gdb to profile Ruby process itself

Don't do that. Calling `backtrace` may not be safe in the context you are executing in, and (apparently) causes your program to `SIGSEGV`.

Instead, just attach gdb to the Ruby process, and execute `thread apply all where` command. Update your question with the output, and you may get a better answer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, since the answer was practically answered in the related question (Garbage collector cleaning because of Nokogiri text node creation), I will close this one by setting your answer as correct. If I'll ever need to profile something again, your tip will come in hand.